# Vanilla JS in React: document.querySelector() returns null on refresh, but works with hard reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have all this work that I have already done in JavaScript.  I don't want to do it all over again in React-land, I just want the JavaScript to work in React-land.  React is just JS, for [heaven's] sake.  Here's a page where I am importing my vanilla JS file:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../js/accountAdmin.js';


const Home = () => {

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <section className="side-bar">
        <nav>
          <p>My Page</p>
        </nav>
      </section>

      <section className="main">

        <h1>My Page</h1>
        <span>Click on a cell to edit:</span>

        <div className="accountsTableDiv"></div>
        <div className="addAccount"></div>
        <div className="feedbackMessages"></div>


        <div className="bottom-section">
          <p className="info">
            Frontend for MyPage.
          </p>
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Here's the JS file:

```
let tblBody;
const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/accounts";

//wait until the page loads.
window.onload = async function() {
    let feedbackMessage = document.querySelector(".feedbackMessages");
    let accountsTableDiv = document.querySelector(".accountsTableDiv");
    let accountAddDiv = document.querySelector(".addAccount");
    
    let table = document.createElement('table');

    console.log(feedbackMessage);       //null on refresh, works fine on hard reload
    console.log(accountsTableDiv);      //null on refresh, works fine on hard reload
    console.log(accountAddDiv);         //null on refresh, works fine on hard reload
    console.log(table);

    tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    console.log(tblBody);

    console.log("onload() ended");
};
```

The `document.querySelector()` statements are returning null on refresh, but they work as expected on hard reload.  I'm guessing this has something to do with React's virtual DOM, but I'm not sure what to do about it.  What should I do?  What do I need to understand about React when it comes to using vanilla JS?

Comment: The best option is NOT to manipulate the DOM tree manually, but rather use the React way. For example, in order to fetch the list of accounts on page load you can implement data fetching in `React.useEffect(() => { ... }, [])` and then render the table in your React component.

Comment: With React, like a lot of frameworks, the idea is to  get people away from thinking about the DOM and thinking more about their data/state. Part of that, for React especially, is the performance benefits that can be had when you let the library figure out the delta that needs to happen between one state and another. So I usually say "don't forget the DOM; just don't worry about it until you have to" when using frameworks like React.

Comment: @AdamWinter can you specify the framework or build toolchain that you are using? (Next.js / Vite.js / CRA / etc.) Can you also clarify what you mean by "refresh" and "hard reload"?

Comment: @IgorDanchenko I'm running "npm start" and looking at localhost:3000.  The app was created with create-react-app.  When I do build it, I'm using npm run build, but the problem is the same before or after that build.

Comment: @AdamWinter Thank you. While I was unable to reproduce your issue in a simple app create with create-react-app, I suspect you may bee facing a race condition between `window.onload` and React rendering cycle. To guarantee the right execution order in this case, I can suggest the following approach: 1) declare your vanilla JS function as a global function; 2) call the global function from React effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erram and Igor both had very helpful input that got me looking at the right things. After a little finessing, here are the major points I pulled from this:

useEffect() is basically the equivalent of window.onload in React-land.  It runs after the page has been rendered (or after a state changes, if you use it that way).  As Igor rightly suspected, there was a race condition between window.onload and React's rendering of the page. Do not use window.onload in React-land, use useEffect().

The functions in the separate JS file need to be exported in order to be defined where they are imported.

You can useRef() for references to DOM elements that you want to manipulate with pure JS, without React interfering.

In development (npm start / localhost:3000), useEffect() will fire twice because the page will be rendered twice (for testing purposes).  So, you'll want to do something about that.

Here's what worked for me:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../js/accountAdmin.js';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { loadTable } from '../js/accountAdmin.js';


const Home = () => {

  const accountsTableDivRef = useRef(null);
  const addAccountRef = useRef(null);
  const feedbackMessagesRef = useRef(null);
  const renderNextTime = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("This will fire twice in development");
    if(renderNextTime.current){
      renderNextTime.current = false;
    }else{
      console.log("This should only fire once");
      loadTable(accountsTableDivRef.current, addAccountRef.current, feedbackMessagesRef.current);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <section className="side-bar">
        <nav>
          <p>My Project</p>
        </nav>
      </section>

      <section className="main">

        <h1>My Project</h1>
        <span>Click on a cell to edit:</span>

        <div ref={accountsTableDivRef} />
        <div ref={addAccountRef} />
        <div ref={feedbackMessagesRef} />


        <div className="bottom-section">
          <p className="info">
            Frontend for My Project.
          </p>
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

and a little modification to the existing JS file:

```
let accountsTableDiv;
let accountAddDiv;
let feedbackMessage;

let tblBody;
const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/accounts";

export async function loadTable(a, b, c) {
    accountsTableDiv = a;
    accountAddDiv = b;
    feedbackMessage = c;
    
    let table = document.createElement('table');

    console.log(feedbackMessage);       //works correctly now
    console.log(accountsTableDiv);      //works correctly now
    console.log(accountAddDiv);         //works correctly now
    console.log(table);

    tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    console.log(tblBody);

    //.........
    //other stuff here that gets data from API with fetch
    //and builds the table with appendChild etc....

    console.log("onload() ended");
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The most common advice you are going to hear is not to manipulate DOM manually in React app (and based on your code snippets your vanilla JS code can easily be refactored into standard React code). However, according to the React documentation, manual DOM manipulation can safely be used as long as there are no conflicting changes.

> **Avoid changing DOM nodes managed by React.** Modifying, adding children to, or removing children from elements that are managed by React can lead to inconsistent visual results or crashes like above.
>
> However, this doesn’t mean that you can’t do it at all. It requires caution. **You can safely modify parts of the DOM that React has no reason to update.** For example, if some `<div>` is always empty in the JSX, React won’t have a reason to touch its children list. Therefore, it is safe to manually add or remove elements there.

https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#best-practices-for-dom-manipulation-with-refs

While I was unable to reproduce your specific issue, I suspect there may be a race condition between `window.onload` and React rendering your component. To guarantee the right execution order, I can suggest the following approach:

1. Declare your vanilla JS function as a global function
2. Call your global function from React effect (this way you'll know for sure your target `<div>` is already present in DOM)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import "../js/accountAdmin.js";

export default function App() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  React.useEffect(loadAccounts, []);
  
  // ...
}
```

```js
window.loadAccounts = function loadAccounts() {
  const accountsTableDiv = document.querySelector(".accountsTableDiv");

  // React effects fire twice in React 18 dev mode
  if (accountsTableDiv.children.length === 0) {
    // ...
    accountsTableDiv.appendChild(...);
  }
};
```

Comment: This looks like the information I was looking for.  However, I can't seem to make your suggestion work.  I'm getting nothing but error.  loadAccounts is not defined.

Comment: Can you post minimal repro on CodeSandbox? I've also updated the above snippet to include `import "../js/accountAdmin.js"` - maybe that's what you overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

It's not advised to manipulate DOM elements directly using JavaScript code or jQuery because they are managed by React. So if you want to access an element you could use a ref to the DOM node as it is explained [here](https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs).
However, in some cases, you can avoid accessing DOM elements by combining useState, useEffect and Conditional Rendering:

```
const MyComp = ()=>{
   const [data, setData] = useState()

   useEffect(()=>{
      // Fetch your data here and store it in data state to re-render
   ,[]}

   return(
      <div>
        { data && <AnotherComponent fetchedData={data} /> } //In this way, AnotherComponent will render only if there is data
      </div>
   )
   
}
```